# ipython and sublime text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2, r, ipython

I really love how Rstudio has a shortcut for running a line of selected code, this allows for much quicker coding. I notice more and more however, that I need to work in python as it offers a bit more flexibility than R.

I prefer to code python in sublime text 2 and it is very flexible but right now I am copying and pasting code constantly in iPython using the `%paste` command. Does anybody know of a simple way to add such a feature to sublime text? I have looked at some github projects (like http://tinyurl.com/99xoo9a) but they do not really offer a substantial startup guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

theres a thing now called ipython notebook. you can get it from the anaconda distribution. that does pretty much what i wanted it to do.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for now seems to switch to lighttable. Which seems to have this impressive functionality for ipython AND for javascript.

More info can be found here: http://docs.lighttable.com/